# How to convert pcm/wav to mp3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, voice-recording

I'm using a virtual recorder to record voices and it records in the `.pcm` file format. I found an app `freemp3droid` to convert it to `.mp3` but there are some bugs in the app and it has not been updated recently. Is there any other app to convert the file into `.mp3` or, should I look for a new voice recording app that doesn't use `.pcm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The LAME encoder is useful for converting such files. PC applications  can be found here:
  http://lame.sourceforge.net/links.html
- You can try another recorder, like [Hi-Q MP3 Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yuku.mp3recorder.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInl1a3UubXAzcmVjb3JkZXIubGl0ZSJd). This will record it immediately in mp3 format.
- you can use an online converter to do the job. Try for example http://www.mediaconverter.org

Comment: +1 - if you need to convert I'd do it off-device on a PC/Mac. [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is my personal favorite go-to audio tool. [Should import PCM files](http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/playing-raw-pcm-audio-using-audacity/) just fine.

Comment: However I had the software to convert it on PC but I was looking for an app for my device but my luck. Only one feature I'm missing it has not `Pause` option when you start the recording while other has.

Comment: @avirk Hi-Q MP3 Recorder now has pause button and still records directly to MP3.

Comment: @yuku updated it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no built-in audio converters in Android. Your best bet is to use third party library, maybe even a c/c++ one.

Look at this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920

Comment: This doesn't really answer the end-user question of how to convert a .pcm file to an .mp3 file, though. The OP certainly doesn't seem to be asking for a way to implement this in code (as well he shouldn't be since it would be off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

To convert PCM/WAV to MP3, I know a step by step guide here:
http://www.bigasoft.com/articles/how-to-convert-pcm-audio.html

**This guide helps:**

```
Convert RAW PCM to MP3, WAV, WMA, AAC, AC3, AIFF, M4A and etc
Convert recorded PCM to WAV, WMA, MP3, AAC, AC3, AIFF, and M4A and so on
Convert WAV PCM to AC3, AAC, MP3, WAV, AIFF, M4A, and WMA...
Convert PCM audio from CD or DVD to any other audio format like PCM to MP3, PCM to WAV, PCM to AAC, PCM to AC3, PCM to WMA, PCM to M4A, PCM to AIFF, PCM to FLAC and etc
Convert between FLAC, OGG, CAF, AIFF, CUE, QCP, AMR, APE, Apple Lossless ALAC, MP3, WAV, WMA, AAC, AC3, M4A, RA and etc
```

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.